# How to ReWire Individual Reason's Redrum Instruments into Cubase?

Tags: cubase

I want to send any redrum's instruments as individual channels to mix it separately in Cubase.

Comment: Have you tried one thing or another?  Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect each instrument into next "audio output" rack in Reason. By default it is 1/2 occupied by main mix. I assume there should be option to choose next channels as an input in Cubase (it is the way that it works in Ableton Live)